# Disable the button that's not clicked in Vue.JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two confirmation buttons and when the user clicks on a button, it should disable the other while showing the content of a span element when the user clicks on the 'Yes' button.

You'd think it works, because I can only set a default to which button is "disabled". Both should start as enabled when the page loads. And I'd also like to toggle the `btnClicked` class between which button is enabled and which is disabled.

I'm almost there but I just don't see what the next step would be. (Also just started learning Vue.JS and would really appreciate if someone can look at this snippet and tell me what I'm doing wrong.)

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: {
    disabled: 0,
  },
});
```

```css
.btnClicked{
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
   <button @click="disabled = (disabled + 1) % 2, $event.target.classList.toggle('btnClicked')"  :disabled="disabled == 1">Yes</button>
   <button @click="disabled = (disabled + 1) % 2, $event.target.classList.toggle('btnClicked')"  :disabled="disabled == 0">No</button>
   
   <span v-if="disabled == 1" class="showifYes">You just clicked Yes</span>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? You are setting the disabled property on the opposite button on click and toggling the btnClicked class at the same time. This seems to work.

Comment: It seems to work because I can only set a default to which button is "disabled". Both should start as enabled when the page loads. And I'd also like to toggle the btnClicked class between which button is enabled and which is disabled. You're right though that the post should make this clearer. I'll edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this ?

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: {
    disabled: null,
  },
});
```

```css
.btnClicked{
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
   <button :class="(disabled === 1) ? 'btnClicked' :  ''" @click="disabled = (disabled + 1) % 2"  :disabled="disabled === 1">Yes</button>
   <button :class="(disabled === 0) ? 'btnClicked' :  ''" @click="disabled = (disabled + 1) % 2"  :disabled="disabled === 0">No</button>
   
   <span v-if="disabled == 1" class="showifYes">You just clicked Yes</span>
</div>
```

Comment: That works and answers the question so thanks but do you think the approach is different if I had more confirmation buttons sections on the page? Because clicking on  for example Yes would make all the Yes buttons on the page clicked.

Comment: I think that with multi buttons you should use `v-model` to known which button have been clicked.
https://fr.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html

Comment: Oups didn't see your last message. In your second example I think that if you have different couple of buttons that have the same behaviour you should create a component for this behaviour. And get the result in the parent  component.

Comment: Here I should look on how to communicate between parent and child component